# _blank is not working in iOS 13 or above versions

Tags: ionic-framework, uiwebview, wkwebview, inappbrowser, whitelist

I am working on ionic project (ionic v1) my

cordova-ios version - `5.0.1`

ionic cli - `3.19.0`

and using http url's to show terms and condition and privacy policy of my app.
All is working fine but when I updated to latest iOS 13 version the URL's are not opening any more.

I am using ionic - InAppBrowser plugin and use below code to open url from app

```
window.open("http://example.com/terms", '_blank', 'location=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
```

also I used "usewkwebview=no" from link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/492
in options of InAppBrowser like this -

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://example.com/terms", '_blank', 'location=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,usewkwebview=no');
```

But nothing worked.

I tried to update the InAppBrowser to latest version - 3.1.0
and also tried to install WebView plugin from link -
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

But the WebView plugin showing a white screen when app launches.
I added

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

in config.xml but it wasn't work.

Below iOS 13 versions everything working fine. I just want to open URL's in iOS 13 versions as well.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I make it work in iOS 13 version by using "'_self " in place of "_blank" 

here is the code -
window.open("http://example.com/terms", '_self', 'location=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');

But I want to open URL inside my app like inappbrowser

Please help me

Comment: Were you able to find a solution with _blank?

Comment: @Tino Please check I posted working answer that worked for me with _blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this step remove in app browser plugin then add it again -

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

Ref link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/492#issuecomment-543015062

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo cordova plugin ls | grep inappbrowser 
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
vers :
$ sudo cordova plugin ls | grep inappbrowser
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"

1 - sudo cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
2 - sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```